# How to define length of lines to read in from a file

Tags: python, readfile

I am reading lines from a file in Python. Here is my code:

```
with open('words','rb') as f:
    for line in f:
```

Is there a way to define the amount of lines I want to use? Say for example, the first 1000 lines in the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
with open('words','rb') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i >= 1000:
            break
        # do work for first 1000 lines
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a variable to count. I have used i for example below. The value will be incremented in each iteration. When the value reached 999 that is, 1000 times, you can do stuffs there

```
i = 0
with open('words','rb') as f:
   for line in f:
      if(i<1000):
         #do stuffs
         i = i+1
```

Comment: Not quite. That will loop 1000 times over the first line then ignore subsequent lines. Besides, it's generally better to use enumerate, since it does its work with the efficiency of C code, rather than using a hand-made counter at the Python code level.

Comment: No it wont loop 1000 times. You are wrong. @PM2Ring

Comment: @PM2Ring Sorry I figured I have used __while__ instead of __if__ here. Thank you for showing me the error. Fixed it.

Comment: No problem. In that case I _won't_ post the code I just wrote. :)